# Fault in Ole Automation Server

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-xe2, ole

I set up an OLE Automation Server and an OLE Client in Delphi XE2. My two Methods are the following:

```
function TMyCom2.Get_Text() : IStrings;
begin
   GetOleStrings(unit1.Form1.Memo1.Lines, Result);
end;
```

and:

```
procedure TMyCom2.Set_Text(const value: IStrings);
begin
  SetOleStrings(unit1.Form1.Memo1.Lines, value);
end;
```

Now I tried to call both by the client.
The second Method(Set_Text) was working perfectly fine.
But the first one(Get_Text) wich should gather the content of the memo of the server and write it into the memo of the client, caused this exception:

*Exception error of the server!*

To get the Ole information I wrote this on the client side:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aStrings : IStrings;
begin
    aStrings.Add(Server.Get_Text);
    SetOleStrings(Memo1.Lines, aStrings);
end;
```

I have no idea what could be wrong and I was incredibly grateful if somebody could take a look at this code and tell me what the hell is going wrong;D

PS: I already tested it with Integers and it worked so the Problem has to do something with Strings

I uploaded the two projects on Dropbox so feel free to download them:
Client: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjefshdfhx0bxvn/ComClient.zip)
Server: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivkpz6gcmjq9oaa/ComServer.zip)

Comment: `aStrings.Add(Server.Get_Text);` don't you need a TStringsAdapter instance to implement that? What you should get is an AV.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna check out TStringsAdapter. What's an AV?

Comment: An Access Violation. Take a look at the code in Button1, your aStrings variable is 'nil', you can't run 'Add' on that.

Comment: Aha now I got it. Thanks

Comment: hmm seems like I still didnt know what you mean. It says TStringsAdapter is only for converting TStrings to IStrings and not the other way round. Am I wrong?

Comment: Something like this maybe: `aStrings := TStringsAdapter.Create(Memo1.Lines);` `aStrings.Add(...);`

Comment: no i think TStringsAdapter isn't what I need

Comment: What specific "exception error of the server" do you get? Please [edit] to include the **exact error message**, including any memory addresses it contains. I'm suspecting the issue is more likely related to the hard-coded use of `unit1.Form1`, which is absolutely the wrong way to do things.

Comment: Image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qqfe0no53lnetpc/Error.png

Comment: How can I do it better?

Comment: @user - That maybe. My second comment remains valid though.

Comment: Could someone pls download the projects and edit the code in there? Thanks;)

Comment: Nobody wants to download your projects and do your job for you.

Comment: I just suggested this because I realised That people don't really understand what is the problem and they had the Same project, we would Talk about the Same things..Seems like you misunderstood my Bad english